# getting specific mem and cpu values from linux machine

Tags: linux, process

I have this script:

```
echo $(date +%F-%H%M ) $( top -n 1 -b -c -p $ZK_PID,$KAFKA_PID,$AGENT_PID,$ENGINE_PID | tail -n 1) >> `hostname`_top.log
```

which produce the following output:

```
top - 06:32:15 up 7 days, 21:22,  2 users,  load average: 1.71, 1.66, 1.66
Tasks:   3 total,   0 running,   3 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 22.8 us, 15.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 61.1 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 14360876 total,   191296 free, 10837496 used,  3332084 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  3066536 avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 48721 equalum   20   0 12.828g 1.214g   6756 S   3.0  8.9   2176:15 /usr/lib/+
 52019 equalum   20   0 5809096 1.436g   5392 S   1.3 10.5 450:51.78 java -Dna+
 48411 equalum   20   0 4150868 403536   4992 S   0.0  2.8   3:56.87 /usr/lib/+
```

I am trying to get only %CPU and %MEM values for those processes , how can i do that?

Comment: You can parse the columns using `awk` or `cut`, or you can use Python for a more robust, platform-independent method (see `psutil`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this after your script code

```
| grep '%CPU|%MEM'
```

Comment: I tried this one: top -n 1 -b -c -p 48721 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $9 $10}'
which produce the following output:
6.78.9
those are 2 values 6.7 and 8.9 , I want to add space between them is that possible?

Comment: Try top -n 1 -b -c -p 48721 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $9 " " $10}'